# Hide / Show form either with php or Jquery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a problem here which I have solved with two different solutions. I would like to know:

- Which solution is the most secure?
- Which solution is more efficient, basically which one requires the least bandwith for user?
- Which solution in the long run is easiest to maintain?
- Is there a possibility that any of the solutions might get outdated in the near future? Example if they change how jQuery .hide() works or anything else, whatever.

Here are my solutions:

**Solution 1 with jQuery and some php.**

jQuery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $.get( "hide_forms_until_logged_in.php", function(  data ) {
    console.log(data.response);
    if(data.response == "false") {
      $("form").hide();
    } else {
      $("form").show();
    }
  }, "json");
});
```

HTML markup:

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="file" /> <br/>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload"/>
</form>
```

hide_forms_until_logged_in.php:

```
include 'session.php';
if (isset($_SESSION['login_user'])) {
  echo json_encode(array("response"=>"true"));
} else {
  echo json_encode(array("response"=>"false"));
}
```

**Solution 2 with mostly php:**

hide_forms_until_logged_in.php:

```
include 'session.php';
if (isset($_SESSION['login_user'])) {
  echo "<form action='' method='POST'
  enctype='multipart/form-data'>
   <input type='file' name='file' /> <br/>
   <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Ladda upp'/>
  </form>";
} else {
  echo "Logga in for att ladda upp filer";
}
```

And inside the page:

```
  <?php include "hide_forms_until_logged_in.php" ?>
```

I know I could have made a function and call it inside the include there, for the sake just put the include there.

The form itself before posting anything to database has a check if the user is logged in or not.

Comment: You should do it with PHP and ajax

Comment: I can add that the form itself before posting has a check if the user is logged in.

Comment: go with the first one because if you want to change the backend part you can easily change .in first you can use frontend and backend individually

Comment: I'm not sure if your question is really suited for SO, it might be a better fit for [code.review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) Although I'd recommend reading their tour / what questions to ask before posting your question.

Comment: Thanks @GauravParashar thats a very good point! So it makes it easier to maintain in the long run.